# proper udp csum using linux kernel functions

Tags: networking

I have un issue with calculating the checksum for IPv6 packet in the linux kernel module.

I tried the next way:

```
struct in6_addr LINK_LOCAL_MULTICAST = {{{ 0xff,02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2 }}};
struct in6_addr LINK_LOCAL_SRC = {{{ 0xfe,0x80,0,0,0,0,0,0,0x0a,0x00,0x27,0xff,0xfe,0x5b,0x58,0xcf }}};
udph->len = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr)+sizeof(struct udp_payload));
__wsum csum  = csum_partial((char*) udph, udhp->len, 0);
 udph->check = csum_ipv6_magic(&LINK_LOCAL_SRC, &LINK_LOCAL_MULTICAST, udph->len, IPPROTO_UDP,csum);
```

But the checksum seems to be incorrect. Could you please suggest what I have to change to get correct checksum.

EDIT1:
Please find the packet in wireshark. I changed the offload settings(tx,rx) but the checksum still incorrect. I am afraid that the value in the checksum is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Is the source IPv6 address on the packets really the link-local address? Have you verified that on the receiver?

Comment: @RonMaupin, Please check the edit #1. I attached the screenshot of the captured package by wireshark.